# How to get bridge support with /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: linux, networking, yocto

There are some linux distros, where it is possible to configure a bridge in  `/etc/network/interfaces`. As explained for example [here](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Configuring_bridging_in_.2Fetc.2Fnetwork.2Finterfaces), it is enough to use this to form a bridge:

```
iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth1 inet manual
iface br0 inet dhcp
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

I am building a custom linux image using yocto. In my image this is not working. Yocto version is morty, which is already 3 years old.

So, what I need to do to get this functionality? Is it enough to get a newer version of the ifupdown package (I assume that this package provides this functionality)?

---

I installed the bridge-utils package, and I could add a bridge using brctl, as explained [here](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Manual_bridge_setup):

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0 eth1
```

but I do not want to do it manually. I would like to do it by modifying `/etc/network/interfaces`, because then the changes are saved between reboots.

Comment: I think you need to include in your kernel the bonding module (or load it). Have you already done it? (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt)

Comment: @MatteoRagni I can create a bridge manually, but it doesn't work from /etc/network/interfaces.

Comment: Can you try with: `auto eth0 \n
iface eth0 inet manual \n
\n
auto eth1 \n
iface eth1 inet manual \n
\n
auto br0 \n
iface br0 inet static \n
 bridge_ports eth0 eth1\n`? (replacing `\n` with new line...)

Comment: @MatteoRagni I had to add address ,netmask and gateway to that. But  that is what is not working. I tried that.

Comment: @MatteoRagni Ok, I said it doesn't work, and the error is `Cannot find device "br0"`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww Thats not true. This question is indeed programming and development related.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use systemd?

If so, try a bbappend of systemd-machine-units, e.g.:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/systemd-machine-units:"
SRC_URI += " \
    file://10-eth0.network \
    file://10-eth1.network \
"

do_install_append() {
  for file in $(find ${WORKDIR} -maxdepth 1 -type f -name *.network); do
    install -m 0644 "$file" ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/network/
  done
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Configuring bridge in interfaces scripts requires interfaces-bridge - "Bridge extensions for the interfaces".
Extensions require ***ifupdown-ng*** recipe. Ifupdown is not sufficient to handle the bridge setup.

Without ifupdown-ng you can use the pre- and post- commands:

```
iface br0 inet manual
    up ifconfig $IFACE
    down ifconfig $IFACE
    pre-up brctl addbr $IFACE
    pre-up brctl addif $IFACE eth0 eth1
    post-down brctl delbr $IFACE
```

If you provide address and mask you should set it to static instead of manual